# Replace template based on placeholder values

Tags: php, parsing

I have wrote a PHP template code to replace placeholders based on the value provided within the placeholder. For example the content may have placeholders like 
`{ITEM-100}` `{ITEM-110}` and I want to replace them with a text made by the details fetched from db with `item_id=100` or `item_id=110`.

The code below id working fine, and I would like to get suggestions to improve the performance of the code. Thanks in advance.

```
$content = 'Here is the item list {ITEM-100}  {ITEM-110}  {ITEM-200}';    

if(preg_match_all('/{ITEM-.*?}/', $content, $matches))
{
    foreach($matches[0] as $v) 
    {
        $value = trim($v, '{}');
        $val_chunk = explode('-', $value);
        if(isset($val_chunk[1])){
            $item_card = get_item_card($val_chunk[1]);
            $content = str_replace($v, $item_card, $content);    
        }           
    }  
}

echo $content;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to improve the performance of this code is probably by using the [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)-function. This function allows you to search for a regex in a string, and call a function for every match. This function then returns the replacement. This avoids running multiple `str_replace()` operations over the string, which can be costly for large strings.

Secondly, we can use a capture group in the regex to avoid the use of `explode()`. I.e. by changing the regex from `/{ITEM-.*?}/` to `/{ITEM-(.*?)}/` we can ensure that we get the matched item identifier directly.

Applying those two modifications, we would end up with something like:

```
$content = 'Here is the item list {ITEM-100}  {ITEM-110}  {ITEM-200}';    
function get_replacement($matches) {
    $value = $matches[1]; // Index 1 is the first capture group, which contains our item number.
    return get_item_card($value);
}
$content = preg_replace_callback('/{ITEM-(.*?)}/', 'get_replacement', $content);
echo $content;
```

Comment: The code is minimal, works great and easy to debug. While checking the performance the microtime shows the similar result as the code in the question, so it is hard to say which one is faster. Anyways I would use this code and thanks for it.